# How to get flv file from URL of any webpage?

Tags: php, web-crawler

I am able to get flv file from youtube URL, but I want to get flv file from any URL other than youtube, like URL of yahoo video or any webpage containing flv file.

Language I am using is PHP.

How can I do so ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no generic way to do this. You'll have to implement individual solutions for each video site.